# How to get child nodes using element attribute value in XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml

i am trying to get  all the child nodes using attribute class. My code is

```
string xmlText = File.ReadAllText(@"G:\\car_words_xml.xml");
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlText);
var result = doc.SelectNodes("//*[@class='سوزوکی']");           
foreach (XmlNode node in result)
{
foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
{
textBox1.Text= textBox1.Text+ Environment.NewLine+childNode.InnerText;
}
}
```

in this code i have given value for class attribute. what if i want to use a variable say x instead of value so tht output of this code depends on tht varaible value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string variable and concatenate the variable with the XPath expression like below

```
string x = ...; // set the value here
var result = doc.SelectNodes("//*[@class='" + x + "']");           
foreach (XmlNode node in result)
{
    foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        textBox1.Text= textBox1.Text+ Environment.NewLine+childNode.InnerText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [`String.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to stuff dynamic substring value into the XPath string. This, IMHO, is better to avoid problems such as missing single quotes (single quote directly before/after double quote is rather hard to read and you may not notice when it is missing) :

```
var x = "سوزوکی";
var xpath = String.Format("//*[@class='{0}']", x);
var result = doc.SelectNodes(xpath);
```